# How to pass data to route with lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 12 and I have route path with lazy laoded module like this. I have no clue why passing roles in data object like this is not working. Wehn I am trying to read data in my AuthGuard, data object is empty. I would be grateful for any tips.

**route path**

```
      {
        path: RoutePath.Users,
        loadChildren: () => import('../users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {roles: [UserRole.Admin, UserRole.SuperAdmin]}
      },
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
   constructor(
      private store: Store, 
      private router: Router, 
      private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  public canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data);
  }
```

Comment: Can you tell me if you are getting data in route.data.

Comment: @Tushar sorry, I copied my resolver by mistake instead of guard.  Now it is how looks my guard.

Comment: @Tushar  You have right. I missed next function in canActivate, and I was using activatedRoute injected to constructor instead ActivatedRouteSnapshot from canActivate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {
    path: RoutePath.Users,
    loadChildren: () => import('../users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {roles: [UserRole.Admin, UserRole.SuperAdmin]}
  },
```

// Here I'm adding the `canActivate` function sample, you can access the data from `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` instance, here it is `next`

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log(next.data); // you can access the data from ActivatedRouteSnapshot instance, here it is next
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I copied wrong function by mistake. Your answer solved my issue.
I was using activatedRoute injected to constructor instead of ActivatedRouteSnapshot from next function. Thamks!